# "Open With..." somehow selected Adobe Reader; now my browser (and more) is messed up

Tags: windows-7

I had a uTorrent download running, and I decided to turn the laptop off for the night and when I switched it back on today, I clicked "continue downloading" which required me to use "Open With..." on a file which used Adobe Reader and I just selected it in a hurry.

Afterward, my Google Chrome and my gaming client (called Voobly) as well as my computer got Adobe icons on them and I couldn't open them at all (an Adobe window would open up after double clicking them and close back down immediately).

I managed to select Google Chrome itself as the 'Open With' program for Chrome so I can use Chrome now but, again, Voobly and Skype and other programs all have 'Open with Google Chrome'! How do I remove this and set everything back to normal?

And I'd like to add that `cmd` doesn't work either, as it also has the "Open with Google Chrome" thing going which just opens a Chrome page of nothing, just like with Adobe.

Answer (score 0):

Download following ZIP file, extract it and run the extracted REG file. It'll ask for confirmation, accept it. It should solve the problem
http://media.askvg.com/downloads/2008/03/Fix-EXE-File-Problem.zip

Comment: Im sorry Im really bad at this, how exactly do I extract it?

Comment: Just open it with windows file explorer

Comment: And then try to open it

Comment: such that I go to downloads, click on it and it opens a 'please purchase winrar license', yes?

Comment: Ok i just closed the purchase winrar license thing and went ahead and ran the registry editor. says the keys and values in C:/something have been changed. What now?

Comment: That means you have winrar installed in your pc. Follow these steps 1)right click on the file 2)select open with 3) find file explorer and click open

Comment: That's all of your programs will be working fine as earlier they used to

Comment: Please don't use shortcut links. And don't use links to direct downloads. It is better to link to the page containing the download link so users can decide whether they trust the download or not.

Comment: And please read  [How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/how-to-answer).

Comment: Link is not working on how to write good answer

Comment: How to write good answer: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer